# How do I convert a boolean value to an int and save it to a MySQL table in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to convert a bool to an int and then save that into a MySQL table, but I get the wrong values:

Example:

```
Enabled = false;
Console.WriteLine(Enabled ? 1 : 0); //returns 0
DatabaseClient.AddParamWithValue("user_id", Session.GetUser().Id);
DatabaseClient.ExecuteQuery("UPDATE users SET friend_chat = " + (Enabled ? 1 : 0) + " WHERE Id = @user_id LIMIT 1;"); // returns empty

Enabled = true;
Console.WriteLine(Enabled ? 1 : 0); //returns 1
DatabaseClient.AddParamWithValue("user_id", Session.GetUser().Id);
DatabaseClient.ExecuteQuery("UPDATE users SET friend_chat = " + (Enabled ? 1 : 0) + " WHERE Id = @user_id LIMIT 1;"); // returns 0
```

Comment: `DatabaseClient.ExecuteQuery` is your method so how should we know why it returns 0 or 1?

Comment: Why do you want to save bool as an int? That would be my first question. This look odd to me since mysql have bit type witch is a bool (basically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply have the 2 mixed up.
When Enabled is true, the first option will be chosen; i.e. 1

Comment: Yeah but i want it to one line and looks clean ;/

Comment: You want your code condensed into one line? This is the wrong way to thing about your code. Sometimes more than one line is better!